# cshell for windows

Tags: windows, tcsh

Where can I find cshell for windows xp?

Comment: from all the shells on unix, *csh is so .. yikes IMHO ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and change it's default shell by following [these instructions](http://www.zieg.com/faqs/cygwin/#cygwin_tcsh)
<sub><sup>[What is cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin)</sup></sub>

There is also a commercial product [Hamilton C shell](http://www.hamiltonlabs.com/csh.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider the native tcsh*.exe's by Astron: ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/tcsh/